# KineticGWT: The import com.google.gwt.canvas cannot be resolved

Tags: gwt

Trying to use KineticGWT with Maven but got error below. Any help is appreciated. My Application.gwt.xml is aslo attached below.

Application.gwt.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "//gwt-module/" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6.2/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <inherits name="net.edzard.kinetic"/>
  <entry-point class='org.gaoshin.openflier.client.Application'/>
  <stylesheet src='Application.css' />
</module>
```

Maven command error:

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Compiling module org.gaoshin.openflier.Application
[INFO]    Refreshing module from source
[INFO]       Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]          Removing units with errors
[INFO]             [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/kzhang/.m2/repository/net/edzard/kineticgwt/0.9.2-SNAPSHOT/kineticgwt-0.9.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar!/net/edzard/kinetic/Canvas.java'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 3: The import com.google.gwt.canvas cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 5: The import com.google.gwt.dom.client.CanvasElement cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 15: Context2d cannot be resolved to a type
```

In the pom.xml file, I have included the gwt-user dependency. My gwt version is 1.7.1

Comment: What version of GWT are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Thomas for the gwt version suggestion. I also got some help from the developer of Kineticgwt. It turns out that I need to upgrade two things. One for gwt and the other for gwt maven plugin.

The plugin version:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-rc2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

gwt version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Canvas has been added in GWT 2.2, so upgrade your middle-aged GWT.

Also note that KineticGWT 0.9.2-SNAPSHOT is built against GWT 2.5.0 so you might want to use that version (rule of thumb in GWT development: upgrade as soon as possible to the latest stable version; this is a general advice but it particularly applies to GWT)

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include the GWT dependencies?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I have included the gwt-user dependency in the pom.xml.